# postresql not installing with homebrew on El Capitain 10.11.5

Tags: macos, homebrew, postgresql

brew doctor says 'Your system is ready to brew.'
Upon installing with homebrew :

```
brew uninstall postgres && brew install postgres
```

I always get the following error :

```
Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": Operation not permitted
Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall postgresql`
```

Comment: Did suggested steps. Installation still stops at : `fixing permissions on existing directory /usr/local/var/postgres ... initdb: could not change permissions of directory "/usr/local/var/postgres": Operation not permitted`

Comment: At the moment I'm maltreating my VM with all misconfigs I can think of to be able to reproduce the error

Comment: OK I have been able to reproduce the behavior. This is probably a permission/ownership problem. You probably installed brew with another user than postgres. In my test environment I installed brew with userA and postgres with userB (after fixing some dirs' & files' permissions). The post-install failed. Then I executed initdb and after first fixing some other ownerships/permissions I finally get the same error.

Comment: Please add the output of `initdb -d -D /usr/local/var` to your question (by editing it).

Comment: I tried postgresapp.com. After adding the $PATH & the 'pg' gem I am just created a simple app. It looks like it works so far.